# Как создать меседжер?

Tags: java, android

Кто разбирался с таким вопросом, помогите понять концепцию.

Мое приложение это не месседжер, это просто одна из возможностей. Будет активити перейдя на которую юзер может выбрать одного юзера из списка своих друзей и отправить ему текстовое сообщение...

Немного почитал и понял, что это нужно реализовывать с помощью XMPP протокола... Но реализовывать это все самому очень трудоемко, поэтому есть клиенты которые поддерживают имплементацию `XMPP` как для сервера так и для клиента...

Один из популярных это `Xabber` ... И вот тут уже сложно для меня...

Насколько я понимаю

Нужно как то имплементировать `Xabber` в приложение, но он сам работает с уже созданными клиентами `Jabber` ... То есть нужно каждого юзера перед установкой приложение регистрировать в `Jabber` и потом как подключать дальше...

Действительно все так запутано? Или есть более простой путь? Обьясните плиз куда смотреть с чего начать?

Comment: Пользователь отправляет сообщение на сервер с указанием адресата. Сервер отправляет пуш получателю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно взять FireBase. Там есть и регистрация юзеров, в т.ч. чрез соц сети.

1. При старте приложения присвоивайте юзеру статус ОнЛайн, при уходе - оффлайн
2. Прописываете юзеру список его друзей.
3. В диалогах отображаете список юзеров-друзей.
4. Создаёте объект-диалог и отправляете туда сообщения.
5. FireBase сам разошлёт пуши и все участники диалога всё увидят

У FireBase есть даже пример приложения-чата

Comment: Спасибо! Только протестировал , действительно все работает и быстро все подключается... Нужно теперь имплементировать в проект))

Comment: Юрий, а вы сами подключали firebase? У меня просто есть вопрос насчет отправки сообщений конкретным юзерам...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, ну, я его ковырял немного... Конкретно с их чатом дел не имел